# error { code: -32000, message: 'invalid sender' } while deploying a solidity contract to rinkeby test network

Tags: ethereum, solidity, truffle

Getting following error while deploying a solidity contract to rinkeby test network:

```
error { code: -32000, message: 'invalid sender' }
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the error was due to the updated version of **@truffle/hdwallet-provider**

I had to downgrade it to version 1.2.3 to get it working.

```
npm uninstall @truffle/hdwallet-provider

npm install @truffle/hdwallet-provider@1.2.3
```

Comment: 1.2.6 is the last version it works on. Probably due to ethereumjs-tx dependency.